# HTML background image flashing

Tags: jquery, html, css, background-image, fading

I am trying to create a website and the login page will have a background that has a series of 10 or so images that gradually fade in and fade out at intervals of a few seconds. For some reason, when the images change, there is a brief split second where I notice a flash with the background color (white in my case). I am assuming it is because the images are taking a long time on loading in real time, given that these are extremely good quality images on the order of 3-6 MB each. When everything is done loading, it appears to transition more smoothly.

I have the following code:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<HTML lang="en">
<HEAD>
  <TITLE>Troubleshoot</TITLE>
  <META charset="utf-8">
  <SCRIPT src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></SCRIPT>
  <SCRIPT type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
      let imgs = ['joshua-sortino-498896-unsplash.jpg', 'theodor-lundqvist-438530-unsplash.jpg', 'cristian-moscoso-1924-unsplash.jpg', 'nathan-dumlao-576639-unsplash.jpg', 'anthony-delanoix-575672-unsplash.jpg', 'karim-manjra-702188-unsplash.jpg', 'jay-dantinne-499958-unsplash.jpg', 'jeremy-bishop-346050-unsplash.jpg', 'robert-tudor-704838-unsplash.jpg', 'john-towner-126926-unsplash.jpg', 'bady-qb-751603-unsplash.jpg', 'caleb-miller-738108-unsplash.jpg', 'christopher-czermak-705859-unsplash.jpg', 'jonathan-gallegos-727409-unsplash.jpg', 'justin-lane-753659-unsplash.jpg', 'michael-liao-725983-unsplash.jpg', 'raphael-nogueira-559166-unsplash.jpg', 'robin-noguier-572033-unsplash.jpg', 'sorasak-252182-unsplash.jpg', 'usukhbayar-gankhuyag-726907-unsplash.jpg'];
      $(function () {
          let i = 0;
          setInterval(function () {
              i++;
              if (i == imgs.length) {
                  i = 0;
              }
                  $('body').css('background-image', 'url(../images/backgrounds/' + imgs[i] + ')');
          }, 5000);
      });
    });
  </SCRIPT>
  <STYLE>
  body {
      background-image: url('../images/backgrounds/sorasak-252182-unsplash.jpg');
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
      background-attachment: fixed;
      background-position: center;
      background-size: cover;
      opacity: 1.0;
      transition: background 4s cubic-bezier(0.4, 0, 1, 1);
  }
  </STYLE>
</HEAD>
<BODY>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Is there a better way of accomplishing this background fading effect than what I currently have here? Any suggestions or tips to make this better? Thanks a ton!

Answer (score 0):

You can preload images so they are ready to go when they eventually need to transition.

```
function preloader() {
    if (document.images) {
        var img1 = new Image();
        var img2 = new Image();
        var img3 = new Image();

        img1.src = "http://domain.tld/path/to/image-001.gif";
        img2.src = "http://domain.tld/path/to/image-002.gif";
        img3.src = "http://domain.tld/path/to/image-003.gif";
    }
}
function addLoadEvent(func) {
    var oldonload = window.onload;
    if (typeof window.onload != 'function') {
        window.onload = func;
    } else {
        window.onload = function() {
            if (oldonload) {
                oldonload();
            }
            func();
        }
    }
}
addLoadEvent(preloader);
```

Answer (score 0):

Other option is a unique image with all backgrounds and you change the range displayed in css with "#bg{clip: top, right, bottom, left;}". Problem: your bg can have a long time load. 
Preload is good idea! But with all background in one image you can any (or part of) image when you to open page.
Preload Problem: with preloader your bg will display only after loaded all imagens!

Soluction for preload problem: You can a array that control how image has loaded and change btw images.

```
function nextBg(){
if(this.currentImage < this.arrayLoadedImagens.length)
  this.currentImege++
else
  this.currentImage = 0;
}
```